# Dynamic ng-click along with $compile fires click event two times on single click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have added dynamic HTML containing a div tag.

And I have bound ng-click to it dynamically as:

```
$('#likePulseButton' + item.nid).attr('ng-click', 'likePulseObject(' + item.nid + ')');
```

After this, I have compiled it as:

```
$compile($('#likePulseButton' + item.nid))($scope);
```

But when we click on this element, it fires click event two times, even if we have clicked only once.

Some help would be really appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Even I got stuck once doing something similar

After trying different things I realized `ng-click` which is already compile is compiled a second time when `$compile($('#likePulseButton' + item.nid))($scope);` is called.

To resolve this issue, only need to compile the altered/affected elements i.e `var elem= $compile($('#likePulseButton' + item.nid);`

by replacing `$compile($('#likePulseButton' + item.nid))($scope);` with `$compile(elem)(scope)`;

According to [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

> Double compilation occurs when an already compiled part of the DOM gets compiled again. This is an undesired effect and can lead to misbehaving directives, performance issues, and memory leaks. Refer to the Compiler Guide section on double compilation for an in-depth explanation and ways to avoid it.

Check this [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler#double-compilation-and-how-to-avoid-it) for more.